# Simplify Kronecker Delta expression

Tags: summation, xact

How to obtain Kronecker delta summation rule using Wolfram Mathematica:
    $$
\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}
$$

The following code does not produce the result.

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], {j, 1, 3}]
```

It gives the following output instead.
    $$
\delta_{i1}\delta_{1k}+\delta_{i2}\delta_{2k}+\delta_{i3}\delta_{3k}
$$

May be this can be done by using xAct package?

Comment: Why should it simplify to your from? Put $i=k=4$.

Comment: You're right. I didn't mean that 3D space in general. But I need to simplify such summations without additional assumptions of the dimension of the space.

Comment: Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], j] // Simplify; does not provide the desired result.

Comment: xAct can do this. It would be something like declaring DefManifold[M, 3, {i, j, k, l}] and then using (note the need to match up/down indices):

In[]:= delta[-i, j] delta[-j, k]
Out[]= delta[-i, k]

Comment: This is relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202373/how-can-i-automate-this-tensor-computation

Answer (score 5):

You might consider using DiscreteDelta[i-j] instead of KroneckerDelta[i,j]. With this substitution, the desired simplification occurs automatically:

```
Sum[DiscreteDelta[i - j] DiscreteDelta[j - k], {j, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
DiscreteDelta[i - k]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Do you know packages for Wolfram that do the simplifications of kronecker delta expression faster than DiscreteDelta?

Answer (score 3):

This work, but doesn't give the answer in the terms of `KronekerDelta` function:

```
Simplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], {j, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], 
 i \[Element] Integers && k \[Element] Integers]
```

$$
\begin{cases}
 1 & i=k \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$
If parameters $i$, $k$ etc which should be integer are known, this command changes this piecewise function into `KronekerDelta`:

```
       kroneckerReduce[expr_, freeindexes_] :=FullSimplify[expr, freeindexes \[Element] Integers] /. 
  Piecewise[{{1, freeindex1_ == freeindex2_}}, 0] -> KroneckerDelta[freeindex1, freeindex2]
```

as in

```
kroneckerReduce[Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], {j, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], {i, k}]
```

$\delta _{i,k}$

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Do you know packages for Wolfram that do the simplifications of kronecker delta expressions?

Comment: @IlyaBryukhanov no.

Answer (score 0):

Not very satisfactory, but it works for specific values of $i$ or $k$

```
Table[Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 3}]

(*{KroneckerDelta[1, k], KroneckerDelta[2, k], KroneckerDelta[3, k]}*}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215350/tensor-contraction):

```
    Subscript[δ, i_, j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j];
    ruleDelta = 
      KroneckerDelta[1, i_] KroneckerDelta[1, k_] + 
  KroneckerDelta[2, i_] KroneckerDelta[2, k_] + 
  KroneckerDelta[3, i_] KroneckerDelta[3, 
    k_] -> Subscript[δ, i, k]
Sum[Subscript[δ, i, j]*Subscript[δ, j, k], {j, 1,3}] /. ruleDelta
```