# Tensor contraction

Tags: linear-algebra, vector, tensors, homework

How do I let mathematica compute a tensor contraction like

$\delta_{ab}\delta_{bc}$

with an output

$\delta_{ac}$

efficiently?

I tried TensorContract and TensorReduce but they were not helpful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They are helpful see e.g. [Contracting with Levi-Civita (totally antisymmetric) tensor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42964/contracting-with-levi-civita-totally-antisymmetric-tensor/42966#42966).

Comment: It depends on what you want to do: For numerical tensors  Dot[ ] whould be the tool of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straightforward way to implement Kronecker Delta is as follows:

```
SetAttributes[\[Delta], Orderless];
\[Delta][a_, b_] f_[c___, b_, d__] ^:= f[c, a, d] /; ! NumericQ[b];
\[Delta][a_, a_] := dim /; ! NumericQ[a];
\[Delta][a_, b_] := Boole[a == b] /; NumericQ[a] && NumericQ[b];
Format[\[Delta][a_, b_]] := Subscript[\[Delta], a, b];
```

where **dim** is the dimension of the vector space. We see that it satisfies required conditions:

```
In[1]:= {\[Delta][a, b] \[Delta][b, d], \[Delta][a, b] f[b, c], \[Delta][a, b] == \[Delta][b, a], \[Delta][1, 2], \[Delta][1, 1], \[Delta][a, a]}
Out[1]:= {Subscript[\[Delta], a, d], f[a, c], True, 0, 1,dim}
```

In other words, for the input

> $\left\{\delta _{a,b} \delta _{b,d},\delta _{a,b} f(b,c),\delta _{a,b}=\delta
>    _{b,a},\delta _{1,2},\delta _{1,1},\delta _{a,a}\right\}$

we get the expected output:

> $\left\{\delta _{a,d},f(a,c),\text{True},0,1,dim\right\}$

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Subscript[δ, i_, j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j];
    ruleDelta = 
      KroneckerDelta[1, i_] KroneckerDelta[1, k_] + 
  KroneckerDelta[2, i_] KroneckerDelta[2, k_] + 
  KroneckerDelta[3, i_] KroneckerDelta[3, 
    k_] -> Subscript[δ, i, k]
```

On your screen it looks as follows:

[image]

Then

```
Sum[Subscript[δ, i, j]*Subscript[δ, j, k], {j, 1,3}] /. ruleDelta

(* KroneckerDelta[i, k] *)
```

Looking as

[image]

on the screen.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. However, it does not work if these $\delta$s are multiplied with something else, even with a constant. Is there anything more general available?

Comment: Well, as usually, you may write the rule a bit differently: `ruleDelta = 
 a__*KroneckerDelta[1, i_] KroneckerDelta[1, k_] -> 
  a*(Subscript[\[Delta], i, k] - 
     KroneckerDelta[2, i] KroneckerDelta[2, k] - 
     KroneckerDelta[3, i] KroneckerDelta[3, k])` then `Sum[b*Subscript[\[Delta], i, j]*Subscript[\[Delta], j, k], {j, 1, 
    3}] /. ruleDelta // Simplify` yields what you expect.